# Using vpd function compiles but doesnt show results in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, function

I have to apply VPD and i created a function. I took the student_no from student table and according to that student_no the vpd will show that student's info from enrol table. But everytime im doing select * from oe.enrol it says no rows selected. If i dont apply vpd it shows all the output, so the grant is working, but only applying this function its says no rows selected. Please anyone suggest anything.

```
connect sec_admin/welcome1;
CREATE or REPLACE function f_policy_enrol
(schema in varchar2, tab in varchar2)
return varchar2
as
v_student_no number:=0;
is_student number:=0;
v_user varchar2(100);
out_string varchar2(400) default '1=2';
begin
v_user := sys_context('userenv','session_user');
begin
SELECT e.student_no into v_student_no from oe.STUDENT e where   e.student_no = v_user;
is_student:=1;
exception
when no_data_found then
v_student_no := 0;
end;
if is_student=1 then
out_string := out_string||'or student_no='||v_student_no||'';
end if;
return out_string;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the look of this line:

```
SELECT e.student_no into v_student_no from oe.STUDENT e where   e.student_no = v_user;
```

Did you mean something like `e.student_username = v_user` instead of `e.student_no = v_user`?  (I don't know what columns your table has, so I'm guessing at their names.)

Incidentally, for debugging VPD policies, have you tried using [`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_output.htm#i1000105) within your policy function?  If you're in SQL*Plus and have entered `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`, I would expect output generated during a VPD policy function to be displayed when you run a query that uses the policy.  (However, I'm afraid I can't verify that right now.  VPD is only available in Oracle Enterprise Edition, and I only have access to XE at the moment.)